# Black artifacts in some rendered images of a text

Tags: rendering

I'm a complete newbie and was wondering if I had set up something wrong.

I used the 20th Century fox blend and successfully rendered 600 jpg images. Looking good, except that about 30% images have a corrupt T in "Century".

I've spent several hours going through about 200 frames trying to smooth the error out with Gimp. Just wondering what cause the fault and if there is any way to correct it a bit quicker..
[image: Little t bad]

[image: Big T bad]

Comment: go into the text and select all polygons and Ctrl + N to recalc normals.

Comment: You may have some overlapping faces (non manifold objects)... You should check the topology.

Comment: Looks like there is a youtube answer.
I'm trying it now.. Right click on the text,
Alt+C and click on Mesh from text. [YouTube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l1BkEqSp74) So it looks like I can do it that way after all - Thanks Rendering now. so will tell you the outcome in 8 hours..... 6 hours later and 3/4 the way through and every image is perfect. After the camera stopped moving in the original, the fault disappeared anyway, so I know the rest of the sequence is going to be excellent.
Cheers guys!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a topology problem.  You can convert the text to a mesh (Alt +C) and try the following.
 - Recalculating the normals (enter edit mode, select all, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
 - Check for non-manifold geometry (edit mode - vertex mode, make sure nothing is selected then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) 
 - Remove double vertices (edit mode, <kbd>W</kbd> - remove doubles)

If you would prefer to keep the text object, go to the object modifiers tab in the properties window, then try the following:

- add a decimate modifier
- set the type to planar

Comment: Sorry, this question will probably frustrate you, but but I click on the text,and press tab to to enter edit mode, then how do I select all? (I thought I'd just press A, but CTRL N just asks to reload file..)

Comment: Nope, I made a bad assumption, you're still using a text object, not a mesh so the given solutions won't work.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hmmmm.I've not got a properties tab..  My version is 2.62.  Is this where I'm going wrong?  Still can't select all anyway..

Comment: The properties window is the one you can select materials, font type etc.  The modifiers tab has an icon of a wrench on it.

Comment: In the "Select" drop down menu there's no polygons, and in the modifier menu there's no decimate, so I might be using a previous version of Blender.

Comment: OK. I've upgraded to 2.7, and I've got a "decimate". I set it to Planar and get "Cannot apply modifier for this object type

Comment: Don't apply the modifier. It defeats the whole point of having modifiers,(for example go into edit mode and try changing your text.) If you do want to apply it, convert it to a mesh first.

Comment: @user165631 Did this fix your problem?

Comment: Yes.  But they didn't like me answering my own question so they put they deleted the answer

Comment: There is a youtube answer.

Right click on the text,
Alt+C and click on "Mesh from curve/meta/surf/text".
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l1BkEqSp74

So it looks like I can do it that way after all - Thanks

12 hours later and the clip is perfect.